# concatenation doesn't work on input submit

Tags: php, html

the variable $res stock just the last submit input clicked. it must stock all submit values which i clicked in.

```
  <html>
<head></head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="">
<p><input type="text" name="textbox" size="13" readonly></p>
<p>
<input type="submit" name="one" value="1">
<input type="submit" name="one" value="2">
<input type="submit" name="one" value="3">
</p>
<p>
<input type="submit" name="one" value="4">
<input type="submit" name="one" value="5">
<input type="submit" name="one" value="6">
</p>
<p>
<input type="submit" name="one" value="7">
<input type="submit" name="one" value="8">
<input type="submit" name="one" value="9">
</p>
<p>
<input type="submit" name="operation" value="+"> 
<input type="submit" name="one" value="0">
<input type="submit" name="operation" value="-">
</p>
</form>
```

php code :

```
<?php       
$res="";

        if(isset($_POST['one']))
        { 
         $val = $_POST['one'];

         $res.=$val;
         echo $res;

        }

?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

concatenation doesn't work on input submit, $res stock just a value of one input.

Comment: I son't fully understand your question but why do you have so many `submit` types? you should have **one** submit per form.

Answer (score 2):

if u want to concatenate something it goes like

`$res = "something";
$res .= $_POST['one']`

`.=` concatenates strings .. what you are doing is that you are assigning the value to the string, so whatever is inside will be replaced by the `$_POST['one']` value

Comment: I have mistake in this code , even if i use "." to concatenate it doesn't work it stock just the last input valuel

Comment: `$res="xxxx";

        if(isset($_POST['one']))
        { 
         $val = $_POST['one'];

         $res.=$val;
         echo $res;

        }`

Comment: does the `$res` contain something? or is it empty as the one you posted?

Comment: the problem is with the form itself, you cannot use `input type submit` with a value, try to use `input type hidden` with the data you want, and it will work

Answer (score 0):

from what i can see from your html, your designing a calculator. so you want to enter each number assigned to a button into the text field. try this:

**html file**

```
 <html>
<head></head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="">
<p><input type="text" name="textbox" size="13" readonly></p>
<p>
<input type="submit" name="one" value="1">
<input type="submit" name="two" value="2">
<input type="submit" name="three" value="3">
</p>
<p>
<input type="submit" name="four" value="4">
<input type="submit" name="five" value="5">
<input type="submit" name="six" value="6">
</p>
<p>
<input type="submit" name="seven" value="7">
<input type="submit" name="eight" value="8">
<input type="submit" name="nine" value="9">
</p>
<p>
<input type="submit" name="plus" value="+"> 
<input type="submit" name="zero" value="0">
<input type="submit" name="minus" value="-">
</p>
</form>
```

**function.php**

```
  <?php

  if (isset($_POST['one'])) {
  $num1 .= $_POST['one'];
  echo $num1;
    }
  if (isset($_POST['two'])) {
  $num2 .= $_POST['two'];
  echo $num2;

  etc...........
       }
 ?>
```